# How to create a graphql mutation with a relation in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, graphql, graphene-django

I have a problem with creating mutations in graphql that contain a relation. I don't know where to start.

For example - three classes of models:

```
class HotelGuests(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True,
                          default=uuid.uuid4,
                          editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=46, default='noname')
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=46, default='noname')
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254)
    tel_number = models.CharField(max_length=12, blank=True, null=True)

class Rooms(models.Model):
    room_number = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    min_vacancy = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=1)
    max_vacancy = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=7)


class Reservations(models.Model):
    BOOKING_STATUS = {
        (0, 'Do zatwierdzenia'),
        (1, 'Zatwierdzona'),
        (2, 'Zrealizowana'),
        (3, 'Anulowana'),
    }

    price = models.FloatField(default=0)
    prepayment_price = models.FloatField(default=0, blank=True, null=True)
    number_of_guests = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    date_from = models.DateField(default=now)
    date_to = models.DateField(default=now)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    booking_status = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0, choices=BOOKING_STATUS)

    hotel_guest = models.ForeignKey(HotelGuests, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    room = models.ForeignKey(Rooms, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
```

Three classes of graphql types:

```
class HotelGuestType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = HotelGuests
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'lastname', 'email', 'tel_number')


class RoomType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Rooms
        fields = ('id', 'room_number', 'min_vacancy', 'max_vacancy')


class ReservationType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Reservations
        fields = ('id',
                  'price',
                  'prepayment_price',
                  'number_of_guests',
                  'date_from',
                  'date_to',
                  'description',
                  'booking_status',
                  'hotel_guest',
                  'room',)
```

And three classes of node:

```
class HotelGuestNode(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = HotelGuests
        filter_fields = ['id',
                         'name',
                         'lastname',
                         'email',
                         'tel_number']
        interfaces = (relay.Node, )


class RoomNode(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Rooms
        filter_fields = ['id',
                         'room_number',
                         'min_vacancy',
                         'max_vacancy']
        interfaces = (relay.Node, )


class ReservationNode(DjangoObjectType):

    in_room = relay.ConnectionField(RoomNode, description='InRoom')
    booked_by = relay.ConnectionField(HotelGuestNode, description='BookedBy')

    @resolve_only_args
    def resolve_in_room(self):
        return self.in_room.all()

    class Meta:
        model = Reservations
        filter_fields = ['id',
                         'price',
                         'prepayment_price',
                         'number_of_guests',
                         'date_from',
                         'date_to',
                         'description',
                         'booking_status']
        interfaces = (relay.Node,)
```

How could I make a mutation out of this in which I would create a reservation object connected to a hotel guest and a room?

Answer (score 0):

when you declare your hotel_guest and room fields inside your Reservations Model you can create a related_name like this:

```js
hotel_guest = models.ForeignKey(HotelGuests, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="hotel_reservation")
room = models.ForeignKey(Rooms, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True, related_name="hotel_room")
```

Then you can access it in your HotelGuestType or your RoomType using the respective related_name.

This allows you to use them in your Query